# XSLT - looping over elements with the same name

Tags: xslt

I am trying to create an XSLT to tranform some incoming XML data into our own proprietary XML schema format.  However the incoming xml has a varying number of repeating "Location" elements  (see below) and I have been trying to work out how I can loop through them - I have managed to create a variable to hold the max number of "Location"s using the 'count' function but have not managed to quite work out how to loop through this in XSLT - I have searched stackoverflow but (and this is probably my ignorance) I haven't been able to find exactly what I need. I am quite a newbie to all this so please forgive me if I am being somewhat dense.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <RqId>dwdqwfqrfrq</RqId>
    <StartDate>2013-06-13</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2014-06-12</EndDate>
    <AddressData>
        <Location id="A6439ebfe-c7f8-40a0-b95f-a0cc1ebfe7d0">
            <NumberAndStreet>1 Main Street</NumberAndStreet>
            <City>Chicago</City>
            <County>Cook</County>
            <State>IL</State>
            <ZipCode>60001</ZipCode>
        </Location>
        <Location id="A6439ebfe-c7f8-40a0-b95f-a0cc1ebfe7d1">
            <NumberAndStreet>2 Main Street</NumberAndStreet>
            <City>Chicago</City>
            <County>Cook</County>
            <State>IL</State>
            <ZipCode>60002</ZipCode>
        </Location>
        <Location id="A6439ebfe-c7f8-40a0-b95f-a0cc1ebfe7d2">
            <NumberAndStreet>3 Main Street</NumberAndStreet>
            <City>Chicago</City>
            <County>Cook</County>
            <State>IL</State>
            <ZipCode>60003</ZipCode>
        </Location>
        <Location id="A6439ebfe-c7f8-40a0-b95f-a0cc1ebfe7d3">
            <NumberAndStreet>4 Main Street</NumberAndStreet>
            <City>Chicago</City>
            <County>Cook</County>
            <State>IL</State>
            <ZipCode>60004</ZipCode>
        </Location>
        <Location id="A6439ebfe-c7f8-40a0-b95f-a0cc1ebfe7d5">
            <NumberAndStreet>5 Main Street</NumberAndStreet>
            <City>Chicago</City>
            <County>Cook</County>
            <State>IL</State>
            <ZipCode>60005</ZipCode>
        </Location>
    </AddressData>
</Root>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What does your expected output XML look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in terms of procedural languages. XSLT is a declarative language, and there is no sense of *"looping over"* a list of elements.

Just write a template like

```
<xsl:template match="Location">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

and it will be applied to all `Location` elements that are encountered.